# Laravel relationship using several columns and tables

Tags: php, laravel

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a model related to another through 2 fields. One of those fields is on the field in question, and the other can be gotten through a 3rd model.

Compoship can solve the problem if both fields are on the same table, and I may need to re-work how the data is being stored to make that work, but I was hoping to see if I was missing a better solution before going down that path.

So the three models/tables (and the relevant fields) in question are:

**role_by_profile**

- role_type
- profile_id

**profile**

- id
- profile_group

**role**

- type
- profile_group

The **profile** and **role** table cannot be changed for business reasons. The **role_by_profile** is being added to my work, so it can be changed if needed. Also, **role_by_profile** needs to be defined at a profile level, while **role** needs to be defined at the **profile_group** (the profile parent) level.

I am trying to build the relationship that points from **role_by_profile** to **role**. The original version looked like this (ignore whether or not BelongsTo is the correct relationship or not):

```
public function role(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_type', 'type')->where('profile_group', $this->profile->profile_group);
}
```

And this worked until it was used in a bit of code that used eager loading. This led me down the path of Compoship. However, that seems only to support multi-column relationships when everything lives on the two tables involved.

So, one option that is not preferred due to duplicate data (and the fact that we will run into this problem elsewhere; I'm just the first to find it). So, while the **role_by_profile** needs to be defined at the **profile** level, I could add in the **profile_group** as well and then just do something like this with Compoship:

```
public function role(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, ['role_type', 'profile_group'], ['type', 'profile_group']);
```

What I was hoping for, though, was something that would let me not have to get redundant data. I tried putting the related data in with dot notation, and it did not work:

```
public function role(): BelongsTo
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, ['role_type', 'profile.profile_group'], ['type', 'profile_group']);
```

I'm open to any other solution that would allow this to work with eager loading, but I fully expect to have to put in the redundant column.